# Disable keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to disable keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> when my Mac OS X application runs. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: do you have a solution for this problem??

Comment: @Risma.. sorry found no solution till date :(

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this ? Your users aren't going to like it.

Comment: ideally user should not like it, but in my case client has asked to do so :(

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the system keyboard shortcuts with:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

void *oldHotKeyMode = PushSymbolicHotKeyMode(kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled);
```

Make sure that you re-enable them with:

```
PopSymbolicHotKeyMode(oldHotKeyMode);
```

Be careful if you do this, it makes it more difficult to switch away from your app with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if it is misbehaving so it can mean that if your app misbehaves the user has to power off the system instead of just force quitting your app.

Tested and working with Mac OS X Lion.