# Disable "Show Help Menu" shorcuts in my MacOSX app

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to disable MacOSX app shorcut **Show Help Menu** "CMD-/" (defined in the "*System Preference->Keyboard->Shorcuts->App Shorcuts->Show Help Menu*") in my MacOSX application. This shorcut is enabled by defaut in System Preference". But it's disabled in Safari and Chrome (not in Firefox).

My application need to use this shortcut to launch an application command, instead of showing help menu. How can I disable it in my application in progamming way ?

Answer (score 1):

You may look here https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut and here [Disable keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311459/disable-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this solution:

`void *oldHotKeyMode = PushSymbolicHotKeyMode(kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled);`

but Show Help Menu action is still triggered by "CMD-/". Any idea?